# Nested Attributes Rails child model não salva

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Boa tarde!

Estou tendo um problema com o armazenamento de modelos com *nested attributes*.

No app, temos *Customer*, que tem 1..n *Contacts*, que por sua vez tem 1..n *Telephones*.

Pesquisei bastante antes de colocar aqui e decidi fazer funcionar somente com *Contact* antes. Bom, a princípio o *Customer* é salvo, mas o *Contact* não. Pelo que eu li, não é preciso repetir o *.build* do model child na função *create*, e a linha ***"@customer = Customer.new(customer_params)"*** criaria e salvaria os dois. Depois de procurar bastante o erro, descobri que, nos parâmetros que vinham do *form*, a hash necessária ao cadastro de *Contact* vinha com a seguinte estrutura ***":contacts_attributes[:0[...(dados corretos)]]"*** ou seja, os dados vieram encapsulados dentro de uma outra hash. Devido a isso, minha outra solução não funcionou (Colocar o ***contacts.build(customer_params[:contacts_attributes])*** a mais).Imagino que isso seja para o caso de eu adicionar mais de um *Contact* por vez.

Não consegui achar uma explicação clara de como isso funciona, mas cheguei aos seguintes códigos :

***customer.rb***

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
...    
has_many :contacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
... 
def change_by(user_id)
  update_attributes(changed_by: user_id, deleted_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
end

def delete(user_id)
  update_attributes(status: false, changed_by: user_id, deleted_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
end

private
...
end
```

***customers_controller.rb***

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController 

def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.contacts.new
end

def create
  user_id = session[:user_id]
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  if @customer.save
    @customer.change_by(user_id)
    flash[:success] = "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!"
    redirect_to customers_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:razao_social, :nome, :CPF_CNPJ,
              :adress_id, :email_nota, :transporter_id, :observacao, 
              contacts_attributes: [:nome, :setor, :email])
end
```

***Formulário de entrada***

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Dados Básicos" %>
    <div class="well">      
    <%= f.label :razao_social, "Razão Social" %>
    <%= f.text_field :razao_social %>

    <%= f.label :nome, "Nome" %>
    <%= f.text_field :nome %>

    <%= f.label :CPF_CNPJ, "CPF/CNPJ" %>
    <%= f.text_field :CPF_CNPJ %>

    <%= f.label :email_nota, "Email para nota" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email_nota %>

    <%= f.label :observacao, "Observações" %>
    <%= f.text_area :observacao %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |k| %>
      <%= k.label "Contato" %>
      <div class="well">   
        <%= k.label :nome, "Nome" %>
        <%= k.text_field :nome %>

        <%= k.label :setor, "Setor" %>
        <%= k.text_field :setor %>

        <%= k.label :email, "Email" %>
        <%= k.email_field :email %>

      </div>   
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Cadastrar Cliente", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o log da requisição que você efetuou junto com a pergunta? Os logs costumam ajudar a entender o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
```

Na tua view e no `customer_params` eu não achei o attributo kind será que o `accepts_nested_attributes_for` não está negando?

no `CustomerController.rb` coloca um binding.pry

```
binding.pry 
@customer.valid?
@customer.contacts # verifica se está vazio.
@customer.contacts.errors
@customer.errors
if @customer.save
```

[gem pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)